# Visual Studio file selector

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am new to .NET and the Visual Studio IDE.  How to I add to a form a component that lets the user browse the file system to select a certain file which will then allow me to programmatically use the selected path as a string variable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) should suit your needs. You'll probably need to put a button (or some other clickable type UI element) on the page that will pop the dialog up. Then once the user has selected a file and clicked "OK" you'll just check the response for which file was selected.

Comment: Would you mind giving a little more detail? When I drag that dialog over, nothing actually gets placed on the form for the user to click on.

Comment: Nevermind..sorry I should have read the contents of that link..thanks!

Answer (score 22):

this should do the trick:

```
string path;
OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    path = file.FileName;
}
```

the string path should now contain the selected file path

**Edit: **
As mentioned in a comment below, OpenFileDialog is disposable so should be wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: The `OpenFileDialog` is now a disposable object so it should be in a `using` statement: `using (OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog()) { if.... }`

Comment: quick response! :-)

Comment: Even after ten years I still look after my old answers 